# What is an alternative in MVC to meta tag content url:?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, redirect, pageload

I am working on an MVC project where I am using quite a bit of java script, I am trying to put the following code to my _Layout page:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/NoJScript" />
</noscript>
```

So I was following [this tutorial](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=1137) step by step and the url=/NoJScript just doesn't take me to the controller method like it does for him when I shut off the java script in my browser. I just get a 404. I put the view in its place as well of course. I even tried putting the full path and still nothing. I read somewhere that I shouldn't even use the URL under the meta tag because there is unreliable in some browsers. **So is there a code to automatically redirect me to my controller and action result method when java script is switched off in browser?**

Here is the NoJScript controller :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Pansense.Controllers
{
public class NoJScriptController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /NoJScript/
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult NoJavaScript()
    {
        return View("NoJavaScript");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the view called the same way as its method NoJavaScript:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "JavaScript required";
Layout = null; // <= Important!
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My MVC App</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
To use this application JavaScript is required.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 on `/NoJScript` then there's something wrong with your routes (which you haven't posted) or something's not setup right in your controller (which you haven't posted). Either way, there's not enough information here to help you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sry for that, I updated my question, so how do I reference that method or view now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your action to `Index` like he does in the tutorial instead of `NoJavaScript`. Or you can change your url to `/NoJScript/NoJavaScript`

Further clarification:

Currently, your url in the meta tag will point to the default action on the `NoJScriptController` which, unless you changed your route values, will be the `Index` action. So you need to either specify the `NoJavaScript` action in the meta tag's url, or rename the action to `Index`.

Note: if you rename the action, you also have to rename the View.

Comment: I just had to change url to /NoJScript/NoJavaScript :)
And I just did a test, and it works on chrome, firefox, opera, IE and safari!